# "String or binary data would be truncated" error while updating but not when inserting new record

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I understand that this error comes when we try to insert characters more than the capacity of column.

But what I am not able to understand is a recent output in which I was getting the error when updating in the table but not when a new record was getting inserted in the table with the same parameter size.

Table structrue:

```
Entity 
(
     @EntityID       int,  
     @Name           varchar(200),  
     @FullName       varchar(50),  
     @ParentEntityID int,  
     @ShortDesc      varchar(255),  
     @LongDesc       varchar(2000)  
)
```

When I am trying to insert a new row, it simply truncates the parameter who has value more than its size (*here @FullName*), but when I try to update the same values on an existing record, it simply throws the exception.

Why can't it just truncate here also?

Edit::
Procedure for update.

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Entity_Update]  
    @EntityID       int,  
    @Name           varchar(200),  
    @FullName       varchar(410),  
    @ParentEntityID int,  
    @ShortDesc      varchar(255),  
    @LongDesc       varchar(2000)  
AS  

set nocount on;  

update dbo.Entity set  
    Name = @Name,  
    FullName = @FullName,  
    ParentEntityID = @ParentEntityID,  
    ShortDesc = @ShortDesc,  
    LongDesc = @LongDesc,  
    DateUpdated = GETUTCDATE()  
where EntityID = @EntityID;  

return 0;
```

INSERT Procedure is :

```
   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Entity_Insert]    
    @Name           varchar(200),    
    @FullName       varchar(410),    
    @ParentEntityID int,    
    @ShortDesc      varchar(255),    
    @LongDesc       varchar(2000),    
    @UserID         int,    
    @EntityID       int OUTPUT    
AS    

set nocount on;    
set xact_abort on;    

begin tran    

insert dbo.Entity (    
    Name,    
    FullName,    
    ParentEntityID,    
    ShortDesc,    
    LongDesc,    
    RecordStatus,    
    DateUpdated)    
values (@Name,    
        @FullName,    
        @ParentEntityID,    
        @ShortDesc,    
        @LongDesc,    
        1,    
        GETUTCDATE());    

select @EntityID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Comment: Where is your [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I am not sure how you are not getting this error while inserting. I just tried and was getting the same error. Can you share your code? Tried this on my local: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3 Also this is still an [open issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/339410/please-fix-the-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-message-to-give-the-column-name) at Microsoft.

Comment: Hoiw we are not getting???? OK I will assemble a quick sample for you as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Entity
  (
    EntityID INT IDENTITY
                 NOT NULL
                 PRIMARY KEY ,
    Name VARCHAR(200) ,
    FullName VARCHAR(50) ,
    ParentEntityID INT ,
    ShortDesc VARCHAR(255) ,
    LongDesc VARCHAR(2000)
  );



INSERT  [Entity] ( [Name], [FullName], [ParentEntityID], [ShortDesc],
                   [LongDesc] )
VALUES  ( 'Name', 'FullName', 0, 'Short', 'Long' );

UPDATE  [Entity]
SET     [LongDesc] = 'Here is an updated value'
WHERE   [FullName] = 'FullName';

SELECT  *
FROM    [Entity] AS [e];
UPDATE  [Entity]
SET     [LongDesc] = LEFT('Yet another update ' + REPLICATE('blah ', 1000),
                          2000)
WHERE   [FullName] = 'FullName';
SELECT  *
FROM    [Entity] AS [e];
```

Works perfectly well for me.